# Django cleaned_data KeyError

Tags: django, django-forms

In my Django app i have three forms:

```
class RoomsForm(forms.Form):
        rooms = forms.IntegerField(min_value=1)

class TouristsForm(forms.Form):
        adult = forms.IntegerField(label=(u'Adults'), min_value=1, initial=1, widget = forms.HiddenInput)
        children = forms.IntegerField(label=(u'Children'), min_value=1, required=False, widget = forms.HiddenInput)

class ChildrenAgeForm(forms.Form):
        children_age = forms.IntegerField(min_value=2, max_value=10, required=False, widget = forms.HiddenInput)
```

in view.py i try to clean data:

```
def RoomsForm(request):
        TouristsFormSet = formset_factory(TouristsForm)
        ChildrenAgeFormSet = formset_factory(ChildrenAgeForm)
        if request.method == 'POST':
                rooms_form = RoomsForm(request.POST, prefix='rooms_form')
                tourists_formset = TouristsFormSet(request.POST, prefix='tourists')
                childrenage_formset = ChildrenAgeFormSet(request.POST, prefix='childrenage')
                if rooms_form.is_valid() and tourists_formset.is_valid() or childrenage_formset.is_valid():
                        rooms = rooms_form.cleaned_data['rooms']

                        for i in range(0, tourists_formset.total_form_count()):
                                tourists_form = tourists_formset.forms[i]
                                print tourists_form.cleaned_data
```

but it always rise the error KeyError at /rooms/ 'rooms'.
Can somebody help me with it?

Comment: Is that last part of your `if` logic meant to be an `or`? It seems to me that would need to be an `and`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this line, you are using `or` instead of `and`, so you are not guaranteed that `rooms_form` is valid.

```
if rooms_form.is_valid() and tourists_formset.is_valid() or childrenage_formset.is_valid():
```

When `rooms_form` is invalid, `room` is not in `rooms_form.cleaned_data`, so you get the `KeyError`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but when I use `and` instead `or` I have another error, maybe you can help me with that. So the field `children_age` should apper

Comment: Please update your question with more details. It's not clear what you mean.

Comment: Sorry for my previous comment, that my kid hit the enter button. When i use `and` instead `or` i have another problem. Maybe you can help me with that. So my case is: i want to create the form with field `room`, it is integer field. depending on value of this field, should be created same number of another fields `adult` and `children` and depending of fields `children`, should be created same numbers of fields `children_age`. But when i leave `children` number empty it rise "All fields required". Hope you understand my problem.

Comment: That's a very different problem. You should edit the question above, or it might be better to ask a new question so it gets more attention.